# ContentObserver not notifed after calling

Tags: android, contentobserver

CLOSED: For some reasons it suddendly works. I checked git, i did not change a thing. I just hope it stays this way.

I have a ContentObserver that is registered during the onCreate method of my first activity. I know that it is being called because the logs say so. The relevant code in the onCreate Method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(TAG, "on create");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_list);
    SyncAdapter.SYNC_OBSERVER = new ContentObserver(new Handler(getMainLooper())) {
        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            Log.i(TAG, "On change for sync called.");
            ContentResolver.requestSync(accountInstance, authority, Bundle.EMPTY);
        }
    };
    final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, VOTES_TABLE);
    resolver.registerContentObserver(uri, true, SyncAdapter.SYNC_OBSERVER);
    uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, SETS_TABLE);
    resolver.registerContentObserver(uri, true, SyncAdapter.SYNC_OBSERVER);
}
```

On the other side I have the `ContentProvider` with the standard insert, update, delete and query methods. For example this is the implementation of the insert method:

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    Log.v(TAG, "insert");
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    String table = localize(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbConnection.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = db.insert(table, null, values);
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(Constants.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(rowId));
}
```

At another point i call the insert method like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, SETS_TABLE);
Uri parentUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

The insert method is working, the log 'insert' is printed and the data is inserted to the database. However the log from the onChange method of the ContentObserver is not printed neither is a sync started. I know that the sync must not start immediately, however i would exepect the log to be printed to the console as any other log.

Does anyone know why the ContentObserver is not called?

Do you need any further information? I could post whole classes here, however that is a lot of code.

Comment: override `onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)` and see what happens

Comment: it is overwritten in the super class and calls the onChange(boolean selfChange)

Comment: i missed that... are you sure that `CONTENT_URI`  used when calling `insert` is the same `CONTENT_URI`  used with `registerContentObserver` ?

Comment: Yes. Today when i run the test again suddendly it worked. I checked my git history i did not change a thing. I checked the logs from yesterday again and they did not show the log. But suddendly today there is the log. I have no idea why it is fixed. Thx for trying to help